# disable or remove ASPNETCOMPILER warning CS1685

Tags: msbuild

We are using msbuild to build our .NET solution.

Does anyone know how to get rid of these warnings at the end of the build?

> (Build target) ->
>     ASPNETCOMPILER : warning CS1685: The predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is defined in multiple
>    assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framewo
>   rk.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll' [C:\Projects\Trunk\dev\source\UserInterface.metaproj]
>     ASPNETCOMPILER : warning CS1685: The predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpBinderFlags' is defined
>   in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Micros
>   oft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll' [C:\Projects\Trunk\dev\source\UserInterface.metaproj]
>     ASPNETCOMPILER : warning CS1685: The predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo' is defined
>    in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Program Files

....
several pages of these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommend to disable warnings (they are here to warn you...). But if you really want to skip them you can add "nowarn=1695" to your command line. For example

```
MsBuild.exe UserInterface.metaproj /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release;nowarn=1695
```

Comment: nowwarn does not seem to work in this case.  May be caused by the aspnetcompiler or the web deployment project.

Comment: I've tried `NoWarn`, `DisabledWarnings`, `/verbosity:quiet`, `WarningLevel=0` and `VbcVerbosity=Quiet` and nothing seems to suppress the warnings.